# Find column given name of title row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Given some sheet:

[image]

I'm able to get the B-column's first row value `datetime` by hardcoding column index in [A1 notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts), `"B:B"`, into my `onEdit` function:

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var datetime_col = "B:B";
  Logger.log(event.range.getSheet().getRange(datetime_col).getValue());
  //=> [17-03-06 11:39:47:752 PST] datetime
}
```

But I want the column id given the string `"datetime"`.

It doesn't matter to me if the column is represented as a range, the string `"B:B"`, the string `"B"`, or some other identifier. The important bit is I want to find the column given the name not the other way around.

- Is this possible?
- Are you able to find the function in the [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) docs?

Comment: See the [Tutorial: Simple Mail Merge](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) example and especially the getRowsData() function in the complete example.  This allows you to use the Header row as object keys.  So you can refer to the column without caring which one it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the first row of data to the last column, then use `indexOf(col_Title)`

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var columnNeeded,data,lastColumn,sh;

  sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  lastColumn = sh.getLastColumn();

  data = sh.getRange(1,1,1,lastColumn).getValues();//Get 2D array of all values in row one
  data = data[0];//Get the first and only inner array

  columnNeeded = data.indexOf('datetime') + 1;//Arrays are zero indexed- add 1

  Logger.log('columnNeeded: ' + columnNeeded);

}
```