# Get values by specific column name - App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get values ​​from a specific column using the method `getRange` and specifying the name of the column using this example that I saw of the following question ... [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634359/find-column-given-name-of-title-row)
When I combine it with my code, I got something like this...

```
  function hola (){
    var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ssh1 = ss1.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
    var lsc = ssh1.getLastColumn();
    var data = ssh1.getRange(1,1,1,lsc).getValues();//Get 2D array of all values in row one
    data = data[0];
    var name = data.indexOf('Names') + 1;//Arrays are zero indexed- add 1
    Logger.log(name);
    var lastRow = ssh1.getLastRow();
    var getRange = ssh1.getRange(name +(lastRow)).getValue();
    Logger.log(getRange);
  }
```

I'm not sure I'm wrong, I hope someone can guide me better :D

Comment: We don't know the content of the row of data in the spreadsheet.  You have Logger.log() statements, but you haven't posted the log.  The line: `var getRange = ssh1.getRange(name +(lastRow)).getValue();` has a problem.  The `getRange(startRow, startColumn)` method needs at least the first two parameters to be set, separated by a comma.  There is no comma in the setting.

Comment: Your `name` variable is going to be a digit - that's what `indexOf` returns, then you add 1 to it. So 0 to some number. Then you add this number to another number. You probably wanted `getRange(lastRow, name)`

Comment: @SandyGood It is that before having `(name + (lastRow))` I had `("A" + (lastRow))` and I thought that substituting A for name would be the same.

Comment: @tehhowch Is that what I'm trying to do is tell the method that hag is to bring me the last data of the name column.

Comment: @tehhowch  It worked what you told me, you were right tehhowch, thank you very much I did not think it was that simple.

Comment: The various "method signatures" if the function `getRange` are available on the Apps Script reference documentation. You can learn more about the parameter order there.